# commas with introductions

Tags: british-english, commas

> Reports in the media that *Norfolk constituency MP*, Dehenna Davison has joined calls for *Boris Johnson’s top aide*, Dominic Cummings to quit have been branded “misleading” by her office.

*What is the difference between introductory comma usage and commas surrounding non-essential names?* In the sense, some introductions define the subject of the sentence rendering it non-essential whilst others don't.

In the example: *Norfolk constituency MP*, provides the introduction to Dehenna Davison so one comma after the introduction, but Boris Johnson's top aide could only mean one specific person.

Are these just matters of style and consistency in newspapers?

Comment: If it's the case that *Boris Johnson's top aide* could only be Dominic Cummings, then you've already identified that this is an example of a nonrestrictive clause. As such, you need a ***second*** comma after *Cummings*. Similarly, either there should be ***no*** comma before *Dehenna Davidson* (if there are multiple Norfolk constituency MPs) or there should be a comma ***after*** *Davidson* as well (if there is only one such MP).

Comment: Jason Bassford- some style guides suggest using a pair of commas around a name just to draw specific attention to the name in certain contexts where it is the first mention of the name. Any right or wrong in this?

Comment: The traditional analysis of restrictive versus nonrestrictive clauses doesn't always have to be followed. However, it's the most common way of interpreting the meaning, because it happens to be the most common way of styling the information.